# The process 'D:\a\_tasks\VSTest_ef0\2.203.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 1 build pipeline and a release pipeline that configured for .NET Core projects test (Running VS Tests Unit).

This is the release pipeline:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXkw8.png)

After ran I can see the tests but the pipeline returned this error:

Test Run Failed.
Error: The process 'D:\a_tasks\VSTest_ef087383\2.203.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1
Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.

Could you help me to identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Test Run Failed. Error: The process

> 'D:\a_tasks\VSTest_ef087383\2.203.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe'

> failed with exit code 1 Vstest failed with error. Check logs for

> failures. There might be failed tests.

According to the error message, the problem should be that the VSTest task supports .Net Framework 4.6.2 from version 2.203.0.

You need to check the .NET framework version installed on the build agent machine. If the .NET Framework version installed on the machine is 4.6.1 or lower, try upgrading the .NET Framework version to 4.6.2.

You can refer to [Check prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops#check-prerequisites) to ensure that your .NET Framework version is 4.6.2 or a later.

Furthermore, you can use **task version 1** in Visual Studio test.

[task version 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1nEn.png)

Comment: I am using hosted agents, how can I check the version?